# How to append last column of every other row with the last column of the subsequent row

Tags: awk

I'd like to append every other (odd-numbered rows) row with the last column of the subsequent row (even-numbered rows). I've tried several different commands but none seem to do the task I'm trying to achieve.

Raw data:

```
user|396012_232|program|30720Mn|
|396012_232.batch|batch|30720Mn|5108656K
user|398498_2|program|102400Mn|
|398498_2.batch|batch|102400Mn|36426336K
user|391983_233|program|30720Mn|
|391983_233.batch|batch|30720Mn|5050424K
```

I'd like to take the last field in the "batch" lines and append the line above it with the last field in the "batch" line.

Desired output:

```
user|396012_232|program|30720Mn|5108656K
|396012_232.batch|batch|30720Mn|5108656K
user|398498_2|program|102400Mn|36426336K
|398498_2.batch|batch|102400Mn|36426336K
user|391983_233|program|30720Mn|5050424K
|391983_233.batch|batch|30720Mn|5050424K
```

The "batch" lines would then be discarded from the output, so in those lines there is no preference if the line is cut or copied or changed in any way.

Where I got stumped, my attempts to finish the logic were embarrassingly illogical:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="|"} {FS="|"} {if ($3=="batch") {a=$5} else {} ' file.data
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not need to keep the lines with `batch` in Field 3, you may use

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="|"} NR%2==1 { prev=$0 }; $3=="batch" { print prev $5 }' file.data
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="|"} NR%2==1 { prev=$0 }; NR%2==0 { print prev $5 }' file.data
```

See the [online `awk` demo](https://ideone.com/vkScSf) and [another demo](https://ideone.com/DIMmKS).

**Details**

- `BEGIN{OFS=FS="|"}` - sets the field separator to pipe
- `NR%2==1 { prev=$0 };` -  saves the odd lines in `prev` variable
- `$3=="batch"` - checks if Field 3 is equal to `batch`  (probably, with this logic you may replace it with `NR%2==0` to get the even line)
- `{ print prev $5 }` - prints the previous line and Field 5.

You may consider also a `sed` option:

```
sed 'N;s/\x0A.*|\([^|]*\)$/\1/' file.data > newfile
```

See [this demo](https://ideone.com/ZoPxQg)

**Details**

- `N;` - adds a newline to the pattern space, then appends the next line of
   input to the pattern space and if there is no more input then `sed`
   exits without processing any more commands
- `s/\x0A.*|\([^|]*\)$/\1/` - replaces with Group 1 contents a

  - `\x0A` - newline
  - `.*|` - any 0+ chars up to the last `|` and
  - `\([^|]*\)` - (Capturing group 1): any 0+ chars other than `|`
  - `$`  - end of line

Answer (score 1):

if your data in 'd' file try gnu awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"} {if(getline n) {if(n~/batch/){b=split(n,a,"|");print $0 a[b]"\n"n} } }' d
```